# Long.parseLong("digitstring too significant") produces java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, long-integer, string-parsing

I get a  java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "1.7023484830876092"

trimming the string to 1.70234, does solve the problem, but before slicing the string myself I'm wondering whether its possible to use some java methods to leverage the capacity of the target object.

kind regards,
jeroen.

Comment: What is the floating point separator in your locale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try using the DecimalFormat class:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

```
  DecimalFormat fm = new DecimalFormat("#.################");
  try {
   double x = fm.parse("1.12345678901234").doubleValue();
   System.out.println(x);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

this might work....

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a float. Especially since the first "." is the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps want BigDecimal? It's variably sized to accommodate any number, so long as you have the memory. Use as `new BigDecimal(stringNumber)`. Downside is you don't get access to the standard infix operators(eg. + - * / etc...).

But if you just want the largest value that can be held by a primitive then use `Long.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: im guessing this should be BigDecimal not BigInteger since the question contains a number with a decimal representation.

Comment: BigDecimal does indeed look the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot parse floating point values with Long.parseLong. Use Double.parseDouble instead.